# How to add additional comment syntax to a mode?

Tags: major-mode, comment, fill-paragraph

In general, given a major mode with a defined comment syntax, what do I have to define or change to add a new comment syntax? By "adding", I mean setting some new characters so that they

- work with commands such as `comment-line`, `comment-dwim`, `comment-indent-new-line`
- are preserved nicely by `fill-paragraph`
- get in all other ways treated as comments usually work in programming modes, including the proper spacing after the comment string

(Syntax highlighting will be specific to the mode, I guess, but if there is something more general -- please tell.)

Also, of course I'd like to have a function (or functions?) to apply the new comment syntax like with `comment-line`, which I can then bind to some keys, without having to implement all by myself, if possible.

There are description of some commands and variables [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Options-for-Comments.html), but that doesn't answer all questions completely.  For examle, some modes seem to include the space after the actual comment character into `comment-start`, while others don't -- why? Does it make a difference?

The only similar question I could find was [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/15029/14414), but it's a bit more specific, and I don't know really what the provided answers do.  For C and C++, there must certainly be a way that handles both `//` and `/**/` comments, but that's not elaborated there... Also, I don't want to define a whole new major mode just for comments.  [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/how-to-setup-comment-start-and-comment-start-skip) is close, but unanswered.

---

My concrete use case: I'm working with julia-mode, where there normally are line comments starting with `#`.  The syntax handling of that is, I think, defined [here](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs/blob/2ef6992125a85674532a1e37dacd5c60bee4feeb/julia-mode.el#L664) by setting `comment-start` to `"# "` and `comment-start-skip` to `"#+\\s-*"`.  What would I have to do to make line comments starting with `#'` and `#+` be handled the same, preserving the standard comments? (For the curious, these kinds of comments are used in [Weave](http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/usage/#script-format).)

I set

```
(setq comment-start "#' "
      comment-start-skip "#+'?\\s-*")
```

but that doesn't quite do what I want:

- `comment-line` now inserts comments starting with `#'`, but I'd like it to keep using standard comments (just `#`).  It manages to uncomment lines starting with both `#` and `#'`, though.
- `fill-paragraph` basically ignores the `'`, and behaves as with normal `#` (ie., `#' bla\n #' blub` becomes `#' bla ' blub` instead of `#' bla blub`, while doing the right thing without the single quotes).

What I want is to keep everything related to only `#` the same, but respect the compounds `#'` and `#+` in formatting and uncommenting.  And have extra commands to insert them, equivalent to `comment-line`.

Comment: To add to @Drew's remark: what happens if you `(setq comment-start "#'")` in `julia-mode`?  Does it do what you want?  if not, tell us what doesn't work the way you want it.